# Programmatically added rows in jsp aren't sent to controller in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have 2 classes:

```
public class IndividualRate {
    private String currency;
    private String operation;
    private double rate;
    private double amount;
//controller, getters and setters
}

public class IndividualRateList {
    private List<IndividualRate> individualRates = new ArrayList<>();
//controller, getters and setters
}
```

In JSp I have table and form tag for sending data to Spring:

```
<tbody id="rateBody">
            <form:form method="POST" cssClass="forms" id="formRateSubmit" action="${urlRates}"
                       modelAttribute="individualRateList">
                     <tr id="row1">
                        <td>
                            <select name="individualRates[0].currency" id="listOfCurrency1">
                                <option selected="selected" value=""><spring:message code="label.please.select"/></option>
                                <c:forEach var="item" items="${currencyRates}" varStatus="loop">
                                    <option value="${item.currency}" >${item.currency}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="individualRates[0].operation" value="Buying" checked="true"/><spring:message code="label.buying.operation"/>
                            <input type="radio" name="individualRates[0].operation" value="Selling"/> <spring:message code="label.selling.operation"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="individualRates[0].rate" id="txtRate1" size="10"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="individualRates[0].amount" id="txtAmount1" size="10"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="deleteRow1" class="btn-remove"
                               style="color: #f00; text-decoration: none;" onclick="deleteRow('1')">X</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="row2">
                        <td>
                            <select name="individualRates[1].currency" id="listOfCurrency2">
                                <option selected="selected" value=""><spring:message code="label.please.select"/></option>
                                <c:forEach var="item" items="${currencyRates}" varStatus="loop">
                                    <option value="${item.currency}" >${item.currency}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="individualRates[1].operation" value="Buying" checked="true"/><spring:message code="label.buying.operation"/>
                            <input type="radio" name="individualRates[1].operation" value="Selling"/> <spring:message code="label.selling.operation"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="individualRates[1].rate" id="txtRate2" size="10"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="individualRates[1].amount" id="txtAmount2" size="10"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="deleteRow2" class="btn-remove"
                               style="color: #f00; text-decoration: none;" onclick="deleteRow('2')">X</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <%--</c:forEach>--%>
            </form:form>
            </tbody>
```

When I run this program both of 2 rows are sent to Spring. But the count of rows are mutable. I have button for adding new rows. If I comment second row (row2) and add this with addRow button second row isn't sent. The onClick function for addRow button:

```
$('#addRow').click(function () {
            i = i + 1;
            var row = document.getElementById("row1").cloneNode(true);
            row.id = "row" + i;
            var elementsInput = row.getElementsByTagName("input");  // 4 input tag
            var elementSelect = row.getElementsByTagName("select"); // 1 select tag
            ////  Currency
            elementSelect[0].id = "listOfCurrency" + i;
            elementSelect[0].name = "individualRates[" + (i-1) + "].currency";

            ////  Operation
            elementsInput[0].name = "individualRates[" + (i-1) + "].operation";
            elementsInput[1].name = "individualRates[" + (i-1) + "].operation";

            ////  Rate
            elementsInput[2].id = "txtRate" + i;
            elementsInput[2].name = "individualRates[" + (i-1) + "].rate";

            ////  Amount
            elementsInput[3].id = "txtAmount" + i;
            elementsInput[3].name = "individualRates[" + (i-1) + "].amount";

            document.getElementById("rateBody").appendChild(row);
        });
```

Please, help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The controls name should be `operation` not `individualRates[0].operation`

Comment: In this way I bind jsp element to the property of Java object. If I name it operation it won't work.